# truncate on one table blocked by select of another

Tags: postgresql

**Postgres 9.4, Ubuntu 10**

I have been unable to find this exact problem here, so here it goes:

For each table t in my database, I have a table t_audit. Each delete, insert, and update on table t triggers a function that inserts a record to table t_audit.

Each night, a process truncates each t_audit table.

Last night, a select on table t prevented the truncate on t_audit from proceeding. I did not save what was in pg_stat_activity at the time, but I did save the output from blocking_locks().

1. Blocking pid: RowExclusiveLock, t, select * from t where ...,
2. Waiting pid: AccessExclusiveLock, t_audit, truncate table t_audit,

I am uncertain as to why a select on t would block the truncate on t_audit. As I did not save pg_stat_activity, the best that I can assume is that the select was "idle in transaction". I asked the person who was running the query at the time, and he said he was not running the update as part of a transaction. He did update table t just prior to the select. He did not close his connection as the pid was still active until I ran pg_terminate_backend on the pid.

Has anyone experienced this issue before? Is there a recommended procedure for this other than running pg_terminate_backend on any pids which are "idle in transaction" just prior to calling truncates?

Thank you for reading and taking time to respond.

Answer (score 4):

Are there any triggers in place that might cause even something as innocuous as a `SELECT` on the audit table at the same time as the `TRUNCATE` (although the fact that it's a Row Exclusive lock indicates that whatever is being triggered is something like an `UPDATE` instead)?  From the [PG 9.4 locking documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html), `SELECT` and `TRUNCATE` would indeed block each other as expected behavior.  The relevant tidbits are these:

> ACCESS SHARE
>   Conflicts with the ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock mode only.
>   The SELECT command acquires a lock of this mode on referenced tables. In general, any query that only reads a table and does not modify it will acquire this lock mode.
>
> ACCESS EXCLUSIVE
>   Conflicts with locks of all modes (ACCESS SHARE, ROW SHARE, ROW EXCLUSIVE, SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE, SHARE, SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE, EXCLUSIVE, and ACCESS EXCLUSIVE). This mode guarantees that the holder is the only transaction accessing the table in any way.
>   Acquired by the DROP TABLE, TRUNCATE, REINDEX, CLUSTER, and VACUUM FULL commands. Many forms of ALTER TABLE also acquire a lock at this level.

And even more specifically telling is this explicit tip on that page:

> Tip: Only an ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock blocks a SELECT (without FOR UPDATE/SHARE) statement.

As for what to do in this scenario, if your use case is tolerant of unceremonious terminations of (possibly idle) connections, that is certainly a straightforward way of ensuring that the `TRUNCATE` succeeds.

A more flexible alternative may be to clear out the table with `DELETE` instead, and then follow up with some variation of `VACUUM` afterwards (`DELETE` and `SELECT` will not block each other, but it will block `UPDATE`). The suitability of this approach would depend a lot on things like the growth pattern of the table from day-to-day (simply `VACUUM` may be suitable if its maximum size is not that different day-to-day) and how badly you need that space reclaimed in the short term if it is a huge table - you may need to `VACUUM FULL` that table during a quiet window if you need the space quickly and badly, but `VACUUM FULL` is not a gentle hammer to swing by any means.